# Issue with spray-routing and Future[Option[String]]

Tags: scala, spray

I want to take a function that returns a `Future[Option[String]]` and use that in conjunction with spray routing's `onComplete` directive. But no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it work.

Let's say that I have the following function:

```
def expensiveOperation: Future[Option[String]] = { ... do stuff ... }
```

And then I want to define a portion of my `Route` as such:

```
onComplete(expensiveOperation) {
  case Success(string) => complete(string)
  case Failure(_) => complete("failure")
}
```

Is there a way to do this without writing a separate function to transform the `Future[Option[String]]` into a basic `Future[String]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
onComplete(expensiveOperation) {
  case Success(Some(string)) => complete(string)
  case _ => complete("failure")
}
```

or:

```
onComplete(expensiveOperation.map(_.get)) {
  case Success(string) => complete(string)
  case Failure(_) => complete("failure")
}
```

Comment: Those are both very elegant, but for some reason I can't get it to go. When I run a very simple function that returns a `Future[Option[String]]` everything runs fine, but I have a function that queries Riak and returns a `Future[Option[String]]` and works just fine on its own but seems to silently fail in a Spray routing context. Hmmm.

Answer (score 3):

A Late Answer. Found this to be working.

```
post{
      entity(as[Project]) { project =>
          complete {
            (projectActor ? Update(project)).mapTo[Project]
          }
      }
   }
```

Hope this Fixes the issue

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/FM6mF6JXuNM